# Importxml in Google Sheets working partially

Tags: xml, web, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Google photos forum has been replaced with Google Photos Community and I finally can use Importxml to pull up data from it.

URL: `https://support.google.com/photos/thread/135168`

xpath : `//*[@class="thread-all-replies__message"]`

For some reason, Importxml function is returning only 5 results from this thread whereas this thread has total 18 replies as of today.

What am I doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Check if the XHTML is well formed and that the source code include all the results that you expect.

Comment: See [How to know if Google Sheets IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML functions are able to get data from a resource hosted on a website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/115664/88163)

Comment: I figured it out. For anyone who is looking for it, you can use the RSS Feed to push data to Spreadsheet. Here's the code:

Comment: function test() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("KEY").getSheetByName('Agent Work Space');
var temp = sheet.getRange(1, 6, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
var existingIds = [];
for (var i in temp) {
 existingIds.push(temp[i][0]);
}
var feed = UrlFetchApp.fetch("RSS Link").getContentText();
feed = XmlService.parse(feed);
var items = feed.getRootElement().getChild("channel").getChildren("item");
for (var i in items) {
var link = items[i].getChild("link").getValue();
if (existingIds.indexOf(link) != -1) continue;
sheet.appendRow([]););}}

Comment: Please add you solution as an answer. Comments are intended to be temporary. Ref. [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @Rubén I don't have the checkbox available.

Comment: The checkbox is available when you want to post your answer at the same time that you are posting your question. In this case, write your answer on the answer box and click the "Post your answer" button

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
function test() { var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("KEY").getSheetByName('Agent Work Space'); var temp = sheet.getRange(1, 6, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues(); var existingIds = []; for (var i in temp) { existingIds.push(temp[i][0]); } var feed = UrlFetchApp.fetch("RSS Link").getContentText(); feed = XmlService.parse(feed); var items = feed.getRootElement().getChild("channel").getChildren("item"); for (var i in items) { var link = items[i].getChild("link").getValue(); if (existingIds.indexOf(link) != -1) continue; sheet.appendRow([]););}}
```